# Merge Files In Excel

Tags: vba

I have input some VBA code which is meant to aid in merging files into a single Excel file. When I run the macro, I get an error message.

I have created the main file and also the macro from code source online.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

What is meant to happen when the macro is run is a window pops up asking to select the files to be merged. None may be open or even in memory, but I don't even get to a selection window. Instead I get an error message which says Method 'GetOpenFileName' of object '_Application' failed saying runtime error 1004 .

I am running this in Excel for Mac 16.26 if that helps

Comment: It's because `Appication.GetopenFileName` works in Windows. See this link for Mac [Link](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac015.htm)

Comment: cheers Mikku. Had no idea they'd be different. I have been able to create and run the macro, but it does not do what I am expecting. In fact, all that happened was I had to confirm the opening of the 365 files (1 year) I am trying to combine, which seems pretty clunky. My expectation was for those files to be simply combined into a single file which I can save as a full year. All the columns match and just wanting things in standard date order.  Back to the drawing board I guess. Thanks so much for your reply